# How to access UnsafeMutablePointer struct member

Tags: ios, swift, struct

```
let cfg: UnsafeMutablePointer <pjsua_config> = nil;
pjsua_config_default(cfg);
cfg.cb // Error: Value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<pjsua_config>' has no member 'cb'
```

How to cast `cfg` to access it's fields ? I've tried to find answer in Apple's ['Interacting with C API' document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17)
but there is no info related to this issue.

Comment: how can let be nil ?

Comment: @ogres a let can be optional

Comment: I do not see question mark at the end of your declaration, I am pretty sure you`ll get compiler error for that code

Comment: @ogres, nil is set to the pointer, it doesn't work like with Swift's objects, also compiler doesn't complain about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there *is* related information in the "Interacting with C APIs"
chapter:

> When a function is declared as taking an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - An `inout` expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type `Type`, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - ...

So you can simply pass the address of an (initialized) `pjsua_config` structure as "inout-parameter" with `&`, similar as you would do in C:

```
var  cfg = pjsua_config() // creates a `struct pjsua_config` with all fields set to zero
pjsua_config_default(&cfg)
```

Now you can access `cfg.cb`, and you don't have to worry about
memory management.

Comment: cfg must be a pointer to a struct, not a struct. pjsua_config_default() requires a parameter of type ' UnsafeMutablePointer<pjsua_config>)'

Comment: @gottlieb: Yes, I know. Did you try it? Don't forget the `&` in `pjsua_config_default(&cfg)`. I am pretty sure that it should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Error message is "& used with non-inout argument of type UnsafeMutablePointer<pjsua_config>". Hmm, pretty clear why.

Comment: @gottlieb: My fault. `cfg` needs to be a `var`.

Comment: yes of course, I missed that too. It's working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing in

`pjsua_config_default()` method but to get raw data you shud call memory on your pointer.

Please see working example:

```
var pt : UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>? // Optional

pt = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(1)

pt!.initialize(22)

pt!.memory  // returns your value

// Cleanup
pt!.destroy()
pt!.dealloc(1)
pt! = nil
```